# No matching constructor for initialization of constructor of templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to create a template based tree where the nodes are specialized such that the methods accessing the element of the node and the child nodes return the child node type.  Below is the abridged version of the code.

```
template<class NodeObjectType, class ChildNodeObjectType, class ChildNode>
class Node {
public:
    Node(Node* parent, NodeObjectType* object);
    ChildNode* addAsChild(ChildNodeObjectType* object);
private:
    NodeObjectType* nodeObject;
    std::vector<ChildNode*> children;
};

typedef Node<B, void, void> BNode;
typedef Node<A, B, BNode> ANode;
typedef Node<void, A, ANode> RootNode;

/* constructor */

template<class NodeObjectType, class ChildNodeObjectType, class ChildNode>
ChildNode* Node<NodeObjectType, ChildNodeObjectType, ChildNode>::
  addAsChild(ChildNodeObjectType* object)
{
    ChildNode* child = new ChildNode(this, object);
    children.push_back(child);
    return child;
}
```

The error is in the new ChildNode() call in addAsChild.  Am I trying to do something that can't be done, or have I just made some mistake somewhere?

Comment: Whats the error? Also I have a sneaking suspicion you put the constructor definition in a cpp file (which you cannot do).

Comment: Yep, Borg seems to be right because it works fine here http://ideone.com/YdyRbp

Comment: No, I just left out the constructor for brevity.  there's a comment in there where the constructor would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Node(Node* parent, NodeObjectType* object);`

`Node` is in reality `Node<NodeObjectType, ChildNodeObjectType, ChildNode>>`.

So for `ANode`: `ANode(ANode* parent, A*);`

So when you do something like:

```
A a;
RootNode root(nullptr, nullptr);
ANode anode(nullptr, &a);
root.addAsChild(&a);
```

you will call `ChildNode* child = new ChildNode(this, object);`
or with some replacement:

```
ANode child = new ANode(root, &a);
// error: no matching function for call to
// 'Node<A, B, Node<B, void, void> >::Node(Node<void, A, Node<A, B, Node<B, void, void> > >* const, A*&)'
```

As `RootNode` is a different type as `ANode` (template parameters differ), there is a compilation error.

Maybe you want some `BaseNode` as parent node instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to make it so that the template class was the base node, but I guess I can't do everything as elegantly as I thought I could.  The error message unfortunately didn't give me the fully expanded template, so I couldn't break the parts out as you did.  Thanks again!